# How to search tag by name in GIT?

Tags: git, search, tags

**Is there any possibility to search tag by name?**
In the project there is many tags and some of them have the same (specific) word in their names. Using `git tag` is presenting all available tags, but I want to get tag list of these with a specific word in name.

Comment: `git tag | grep word` ?

Answer (score 28):

`git tag -l` [accepts an optional parameter](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag#Documentation/git-tag.txt---list), which is a (`fnmatch`-like) pattern. So you can use (for example)  `git tag -l '*word*'` if you want to list tags with “word” in their name.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to use egrep with appropriate regex for you. At first glance this one is good:

```
git tag | egrep *word*
```

Comment: I found this to be more convenient